# AWS Lambda function SSL certificate verify failed issue in python code

Tags: python-3.x, url, aws-lambda, ssl-certificate

I'm calling a code a url using aws lambda function. I have added requests and certifi libraries in layers but the code is failing with below error. Could someone please help.

```
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1354, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1425, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)
```